# Whats the last Raspbian OS image that works well with an old Pi B+?

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, raspberry-pi-os, pi-b+

I recently dusted off an old Raspberry Pi B+ (Wheezy, 2015) and promptly installed the latest operating system (Pi OS, Jan 11, 2021) only to find that it was so slow that it was completely unusable, taking minutes to open an app. I've found the repository of all prior OS versions, but didn't find any guidance about which versions are suitable for older Pi's.
Whats the last OS image version that I can be reasonably used on the B+? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: have you tried a different SD card? slow responses like that are usually the fault of the SD card - I'm using the latest version of PiOS on a pi zero and it works just fine

Comment: Jaromanda's point is an important one as the zero and the B+ have the same SoC and RAM -- although the zero is by default overclocked, this is not going to make the difference between "unusable" and "fine".  And lots of people still use (and buy) the Zero, but  I don't think I've seen this complaint before.

Comment: Its a Sandisk Ultra C10 rated (10 MB/s). And appears to be working fine. Is that too slow for the latest OS?

Comment: @Grahame - SD cards "wear out"

Answer (score 2):

I have most Pi from the 2013 model B to Pi4.

They all work with the latest Raspberry Pi OS. The latest models are noticeably faster - because they have multi core processors and more RAM, but I still have a B+ in daily use and it works as it did when new with Wheezy, although it now has a new SD Card.

Buy a new SD Card (at least 16GB) and do a fresh install.

The [Raspberry Pi benchmarks](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-specs-benchmarks) (which would all have been performed on the latest OS) show the comparison between models.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know what exactly makes the system so slow, unless you check what's going on with `top` / `iotop`. Could be stuff running in the background (updates?), or swapping on a slow SD card.

The system requirements for the Pi OS didn't increase dramatically in the last years.